# degree of extension of rationals adjoin infinitely many roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Consider a radical extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which infinitely many numbers are adjoined. Each of these numbers is the $n^{th}$ root of some integer, where $n$ can vary. Can any information be obtained about the degree of this extension, or its divisibility properties depending on what roots are adjoined?

Comment: I don't think any *general* information can be obtained: if **all** the infinitely many numbers "adjoined" are *exact* $\;n$-th squares then the extension is $\;\Bbb Q\;$ itself and thus the degree is $\;1\;$ . If you add $\;\sqrt[n]2\;,\;\;n=1,2,3....\;$ , then extension is infinite...and all the possibilities in between can occur.

Answer (score 1):

The degree of the extension can be any positive integer, as well as infinite. @Timbuc's comment gives examples for $1$ and $\infty$. To get $n$ as the degree, adjoin the $n$th root of $2$ at the first stage, and $1$ at every other stage.